# CSS3 Div Animations

Tags: html, css

I have a simple loading circle that uses CSS3 Animations. After the loading circle has finished is it possible to show a empty div? Any help is much appreciated.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/vJsTr/1/)

Comment: You could listen for the `animationEnd` event in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an event listerner like this

```
 var e = document.getElementById("lastDot");
 e.addEventListener("animationend", function(){$("#mydiv").show();}, false);
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vJsTr/4/